# Excel: Find rows that are duplicates except for two columns

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I am using a dataset that has 6 columns. I would like to find any rows that have an exact match in any other row, aside from two columns. So If my data were like the following:

```
WT    40     SH      VJ       PB        HT
200   4.8    5.6     37       32        71
223   4.9    5.4     38       37        75
220   4.8    5.7     23       31        74
210   4.3    5.8     35       33        72
205   4.8    5.6     37       32        73
```

And the columns I didnt care about were WT and HT, I would want to receive the first and fifth data points as they are identical save for the columns WT and HT.

Comment: Where do you want to get this response, in a new range (pivot table) or in a new specifying e.g. row number of other identical row?

Comment: I would like a response in a pivot table. My data is large though (13000 entries), so there will be several duplicate sets and I am hoping to see all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- At first you need to add a new column to check whether actual row is a duplicate, with formula:
  `=COUNTIFS([40],[@40],[SH],[@SH],[VJ],[@VJ],[PB],[@PB])>1`
- (My range is a table (insert - table), that's why formula might look strange for you)
- then just insert a pivot table based on the data

  - move "duplicate" to filter and filter to show only "TRUE"
  - move all the other columns to "row headers", keeping those at right which are not considered at duplicate selection.

[image]